# getting a string from a list of substrings

Tags: string, algorithm, substring, string-matching

I asked to solve the following problem in a programming competition (facebook recruitment)

Input: list of sub-strings:

```
{"bar","foo","hi"} //from 1 to 100 sub-strings
```

and the sentence:

```
"hellothisisfoobarhi" //from 1 to 1000000 character
```

Output: 12 //the index of the first match in the sentence (foo)

another example would be :

sub-strings:{"hi","hi"}

sentence :"hiJonIamSayinghihiforYou"

output:15 // the index of hi,the second 'hi' because the first 'hi' is just a trick,the sub-sentece is 'hi' hi"

one more ex:

sub-strings:{"hi","foo"}

sentence :"sayingfoohi"

output:6 // the order doesn't matter ,they just need to be beside each others

Who knows a good algorithm for this problem?

Comment: Now you edited you post but, earlier you said "Challenge youself". Do you know the answer ? If yes, why asking here. I am not sure if StackOverFlow is to challenge people. It is to get help from people for your problems.

Comment: No,I don't know the solution,I am trying to get help to solve the problem.the problem is challenging

Comment: Are fooxbarxhi and hifoobar also matches? Can we afford to do expensive preoprocessing of the list of substrings or do they change to  ofter?

Comment: No,they should exist in the main sentence

Comment: yes,but it doesnot form the sentence which can be formed by these substrings.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "form the sentence" - do you mean that you want the index where the next N characters form a permutation of those substrings?

Answer (score 1):

Construct a suffix tree of the large string -- the construction of the tree is O(n) where n is the length of the large string.

Now you can find the location of any of the substrings in O(m) time (where m is the length of the substring) by simply following the the substring down through the tree -- the node or leaf where the substring ends will hold the key corresponding to the index into the large string.

Go through the set of substrings finding their location in the big string, keeping track of the minimum index.

Comment: can you use hashtable or dictionary instead of prefix tree?

Comment: Sure -- but the choice depends on the application. If you are doing combinations of insertions, lookups and deletions, then the prefix tree is probably the best solution. Otherwise a hashtable can provide very good results. Again, it depends on the application.

Comment: Also, tries facilitate longest-prefix matching, but hashing does not

Comment: Doesn't really work... the suffix tree will locate any of the substrings but the OP wants to find a permutation of the substring list in the target string

Comment: @parapurarajkumar Right.. so he would have to go through the set of substrings, match each one in the trie, and keep track of the minimum (I edited the above post).

Answer (score 0):

Another way - concentrating on the substrings rather than the main string - would be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm